# How can I redirect example.com to some.site.com/example while still showing example.com as the URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

To restate the question:

I own the example.com domain name. My actual webhost (courtesy of a friend) is some.site.com.

I'd like people to be able to go to example.com and see some.site.com/example/. The thing is, I only want the URL bar to show example.com/whateverpage.html.

I've been studying and experimenting with mod_rewrite, but can't quite figure it out. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just host a basic web page with an iframe. How complicated is the site? 
Who provides your dns - sometimes they have a web forwarding setting just for this.

And are you sure you can't just change the domain name on the site you are pulling from?

Comment: Yeah, I may just go the iframe route, it would be a lot easier -- it's not a complicated site at all. I just thought that it'd be nice to have a pretty URL. :)

As far as the settings, I only have ftp access, I'd have to ask my friend about that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CNAME record in your DNS that aliases some.site.com as example.com.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

If you or your friend don't have access to, or don't know how to modify the DNS server... Contact the HOSTING PROVIDER that is hosting the site, they should know how to make DNS CNAME records correctly. The wiki above has a few examples of what a CNAME record looks like.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks for the reply.